# groupby and join with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is part of the data of scaffold_table
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
scaffold_table = pd.DataFrame({
'Position':[2000]*5, 
'Company':['Amazon', 'Amazon', 'Alphabet', 'Amazon', 'Alphabet'], 
'Date':['2020-05-26','2020-05-27','2020-05-27','2020-05-28','2020-05-28'],
'Ticker':['AMZN','AMZN','GOOG','AMZN','GOOG'],
'Open':[2458.,2404.9899,1417.25,2384.330078,1396.859985],
'Volume':[3568200,5056900,1685800,3190200,1692200],
'Daily Return':[-0.006164,-0.004736,0.000579,-0.003854,-0.000783],
'Daily PnL':[-12.327054,-9.472236,1.157283,-7.708126,-1.565741],
'Cumulative PnL/Ticker':[-12.327054,-21.799290,1.157283,-29.507417,-0.408459]})
```

I would like to create a summary table that returns the overall yield per ticker. The overall yield should be calculated as the total PnL per ticker divided by the last date's position per ticker

```
# Create a summary table of your average daily PnL, total PnL, and overall yield per ticker
summary_table = pd.DataFrame(scaffold_table.groupby(['Date','Ticker'])['Daily PnL'].mean())

position_ticker = pd.DataFrame(scaffold_table.groupby(['Date','Ticker'])['Position'].sum())

# the total PnL is the sum of PnL per Ticker after two years period
totals = summary_table.droplevel('Date').groupby('Ticker').sum().rename(columns={'Daily PnL':'total PnL'})

summary_table = summary_table.join(totals, on='Ticker')
summary_table = summary_table.join(position_ticker, on = ['Date','Ticker'], how='inner')
summary_table['Yield'] = summary_table.loc['2022-04-29']['total PnL']/summary_table.loc['2022-04-29']['Position']
summary_table
```

But the yield is showing NaN, could anyone take a look at my codes?
I used ['2022-04-29'] because it is the last date, but I think there are some codes to return the last date without explicitly inputting that.
[image]

Comment: Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") . We should be able to copy and paste your data as well as your code, execute the file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.

Comment: I just updated the version with some data in scaffold_table

Comment: I believe your last date is '2022-05-29' so your code doesn't work as posted.  Be that as it is, the statement ```summary_table.loc['2022-05-29']['total PnL']``` produces a 'KeyError' related to using a scalar key.  Not sure what you are trying to do, but this seems to be the root.

Comment: the last date should be ['2022-04-29'] as I posted. I am trying to use the total PnL of each ticker divided by the Position of each ticker on that date (or the last date if there's a more flexible code to get the data on the last date), and make it a new column.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following code

```
# we want the overall yield per ticker, so total PnL/Position on the last date
summary_table['Yield'] = summary_table['total PnL']/summary_table.loc['2022-04-29']['Position']
```

This does not specify the date for total PnL since it's the sum by ticker without regard of the date.

Answer (score 0):

I note the comment in your code saying: "Create a summary table of your average daily PnL, total PnL, and overall yield per ticker".

If we start from this, here are a few observations:

- the average daily PnL per ticker should just be the mean of `Daily PnL` for each ticker
- the total PnL per ticker is already listed in the `Cumulative PnL/Ticker` column, so if we use `groupby` on `Ticker` and get the value in the `Cumulative PnL/Ticker` column for the most recent date (namely, for the `last()` row in the `groupby` assuming the df is sorted by date), we don't have to calculate it
- for the overall yield per ticker (which you have specified "should be calculated as the total PnL per ticker divided by the last date's position per ticker") we can get the relevant `Position` (namely, for the most recent date per ticker) analogously to how we got the relevant `Cumulative PnL/Ticker` and use these two values to calculate `Yield`.

Here is sample code to do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
scaffold_table = pd.DataFrame({
'Position':[2000]*5, 
'Company':['Amazon', 'Amazon', 'Alphabet', 'Amazon', 'Alphabet'], 
'Date':['2020-05-26','2020-05-27','2020-05-27','2020-05-28','2020-05-28'],
'Ticker':['AMZN','AMZN','GOOG','AMZN','GOOG'],
'Open':[2458.,2404.9899,1417.25,2384.330078,1396.859985],
'Volume':[3568200,5056900,1685800,3190200,1692200],
'Daily Return':[-0.006164,-0.004736,0.000579,-0.003854,-0.000783],
'Daily PnL':[-12.327054,-9.472236,1.157283,-7.708126,-1.565741],
'Cumulative PnL/Ticker':[-12.327054,-21.799290,1.157283,-29.507417,-0.408459]})

print(scaffold_table)

# Create a summary table of your average daily PnL, total PnL, and overall yield per ticker
gb = scaffold_table.groupby(['Ticker'])
summary_table = gb.last()[['Position', 'Cumulative PnL/Ticker']].rename(columns={'Cumulative PnL/Ticker':'Total PnL'})
summary_table['Yield'] = summary_table['Total PnL'] / summary_table['Position']
summary_table['Average Daily PnL'] = gb['Daily PnL'].mean()
summary_table = summary_table[['Average Daily PnL', 'Total PnL', 'Yield']]
print('\nsummary_table:'); print(summary_table)
exit()
```

Input:

```
   Position   Company        Date Ticker         Open   Volume  Daily Return  Daily PnL  Cumulative PnL/Ticker
0      2000    Amazon  2020-05-26   AMZN  2458.000000  3568200     -0.006164 -12.327054             -12.327054
1      2000    Amazon  2020-05-27   AMZN  2404.989900  5056900     -0.004736  -9.472236             -21.799290
2      2000  Alphabet  2020-05-27   GOOG  1417.250000  1685800      0.000579   1.157283               1.157283
3      2000    Amazon  2020-05-28   AMZN  2384.330078  3190200     -0.003854  -7.708126             -29.507417
4      2000  Alphabet  2020-05-28   GOOG  1396.859985  1692200     -0.000783  -1.565741              -0.408459
```

Output:

```
        Average Daily PnL  Total PnL     Yield
Ticker
AMZN            -9.835805 -29.507417 -0.014754
GOOG            -0.204229  -0.408459 -0.000204
```

Comment: Do you need any additional help with your question?